# Android How to get random sqlite data?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my DateBaseHelper
         public Cursor getQuestionsFromQuizID(int quizID){

```
             Integer quiz = Integer.valueOf(quizID);

             return myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Questions where quizID ="+quiz.toString(), null );

     }

     public Cursor getAnswersFromQuestionID(int questionID, int quizID){

             Integer question = Integer.valueOf(questionID);
             Integer quiz = Integer.valueOf(quizID);

             return myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Answers where questionID = "+question.toString()+" and quizID = "+quiz.toString(), null );
     }

    public Boolean isAnswerCorrect(int answerID) {

            Integer answer = Integer.valueOf(answerID);
            int correctBit;

            Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Answers where _id ="
                            + answer.toString(), null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            correctBit = cursor.getInt(3);

            if (correctBit == 1) {
                    return true;
            } else {
                    return false;
            }

    }

    public int getQuestionCountByQuizID(int quizID){

            Integer quiz = Integer.valueOf(quizID);

            Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Questions where quizID ="+quiz.toString(), null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            return cursor.getCount();

    }
```

...And I have quiz activity with method

private void getNextQuestion() {
                String question;

```
            // set question count text at the top of screen using string
            // concatenation
            Integer currentCount = new Integer(curQuestion + 1);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.questioncount)).setText("Question "
                            + currentCount.toString() + " of "
                            + totalQuestionCount.toString());

            // get quizID based on which button was pressed on PickQuizActivity
            int quizID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("quizID");

            // use returned cursor to get question as string
            Cursor questionCursor = myDbHelper.getQuestionsFromQuizID(quizID);

            questionCursor.moveToPosition(curQuestion);

            // getString(3): gets the zero-indexed column 2 from current row cursor
            // is on
            question = questionCursor.getString(2);

            // update UI to show question pulled from database
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.question)).setText(question);

            Cursor answerCursor = myDbHelper.getAnswersFromQuestionID(
                            curQuestion + 1, quizID);

            // set each answer text, there will always be 4 answers
            // also collect questionID for isCorrect check when onClick is called
            answerCursor.moveToFirst();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1)).setText(answerCursor
                            .getString(4));
            answerID1 = answerCursor.getInt(0);

            answerCursor.moveToNext();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2)).setText(answerCursor
                            .getString(4));
            answerID2 = answerCursor.getInt(0);

            answerCursor.moveToNext();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3)).setText(answerCursor
                            .getString(4));
            answerID3 = answerCursor.getInt(0);

            answerCursor.moveToNext();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4)).setText(answerCursor
                            .getString(4));
            answerID4 = answerCursor.getInt(0);

            // increment question counter, will be used to retrieve next question
            curQuestion++;

            // set flag for last question reached
            if (questionCursor.isLast()) {
                    lastQuestionReached = true;
            }
    }
```

So... When I wont to show random question, I edit sql, just add SORT BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
and my questions get mix up with answers...

Can anybody know solution how to get random question without repeat?
And how to aviod mixing data from question and answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an extra column in the sqlite data that would be a 0 if not used, or a 1 if used.  I would mark that the question had been used already with a 1.  You can query the database to only return questions with that field at 0.  If no questions are available with a 0 (they've all been used) just reset all values in that column to 0 and all questions are equally available again.

This will help if you are having multiple sessions, and want to make sure that, over time, all questions get hit.

I'm assuming you store your answers on the same row as your question.

I would first do a query to get 1 question/answer pair that had not been used.  Then, of course, mark it as used.  I would use that as the "question".  Then I would do a second query for 3 or 4 more question/answer pairs, and don't worry if they are used or not.  Take those wrong answers, and randomly mix them with the right answer for a multiple choice question.

Comment: tnank you for your answer. can you tell me how to solve problem with mixing data from questions and answers?

Comment: edited answer above.  Feel free to ask more questions on this, I'm just chilling out at home today.